# Add new product type or vendor through Shopify API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, shopify

Creating a new product with the Shopify API rubygem works great.
However my app needs to be able to create new product types and/or vendors.

I'm finding that when I POST with a new product type or vendor with the create product request, the Shopify server returns 500.

Is there a way to create these through the API??

Comment: Can you show us the backtrace (which you can find in the logs) - that may help us figure out what's going wrong for you.

Comment: If you could include an example of what you are posting and the code used to generate the post.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's actually related to how we send product tags in the POST that's breaking it. Products without tags are still posting through just fine.